# Autoplay next youtube video

Tags: google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

Youtube has a `autoplay` feature wherein once a video finishes, the next one automatically starts playing.

Is it possible to `autoplay` the next video from within a chrome extension, using the youtube-api or otherwise? I'm trying to skip some videos and directly play the next one in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YouTube I[Frame Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) to autoplay YouTube videos. To see how to use Youtube player API in Chrome extension over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244379/youtube-player-api-in-chrome-extension).